# All content from site collection is corrupted? How to solve?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, site-collection

I can't add items to any list, library ... in site or subsites. 
I also can not create sites, lists, or libraries.

This started Friday last week while I was debugging a webpart.
They all present this error:

[image]

The stack trace is:
[COMException (0x80131904): 0x80131904]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl) +106

[SPException]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +170
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.CreateListFromFormPost(String bstrUrl, String& pbstrGuid, String& pbstrNextUrl) +321
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.CreateListFromRpc(NameValueCollection queryString, Uri& nextUrl) +1519
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.NewListPage.BtnOk_Click(Object sender, EventArgs args) +454
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +126
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5022

Answer (score 1):

After analyzing the logs in server, I noticed the most was related to database.
So  .. also analyzing the exceptions that appear when trying to create some kind of content + the logs, I found reports of the same errors being problem with server disk space and configuration in Data-base.

After that I asked the DBA to analyze the sharepoint base. He erased some logs from the base, and so it worked again.

Here are some references:

> [Server error: The URL is invalid. It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder or refer to a valid file that is not in the current Web](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/server-error-the-url-is-invalid-it-may-refer-to-a-nonexistent-file-or-folder-o)
>
> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/4cadb1a7-d933-4b35-b115-2b5e2bb1d504/cannot-complete-this-action-the-url-pageshomeaspx-is-invalid-it-may-refer-to-a-nonexistent?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious