# can not edit page or add new page SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, edit

when i was edit page or add new page on my website this error will appear [image]

please help me how to solve it

Comment: Did you try to do any of suggestions from this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/39553/server-error-the-url-is-invalid-it-may-refer-to-a-nonexistent-file-or-folder-o ?

Comment: Does this issue happen for all pages? What name did you use when creating page?You need to make sure the name of the page is valid. If this issue still exists, you can check ULS log to find more information about this issue.